# Compiling of complex_Bessel_function library - linking with Fortran code - mex file

Tags: c++, fortran, libraries, mex, bessel-functions

I have made a .cpp code that uses the following online library:

[Complex_Bessel_functions](https://github.com/valandil/complex_bessel).

I want to make a .mex file out of my code. When I am typing:

```
mex GUSTAVsolution.cpp
```

Matlab gives the following errors:

```
Error using mex
/tmp/mex_7456790284416_24518/GUSTAVsolution.o: In function `MIEsolution::Spherical_Hankel_function(unsigned int,
std::complex<double>, int)':
GUSTAVsolution.cpp:(.text+0x18c): undefined reference to `zbesh_wrap'
GUSTAVsolution.cpp:(.text+0x28e): undefined reference to `zbesh_wrap'
/tmp/mex_7456790284416_24518/GUSTAVsolution.o: In function `MIEsolution::Spherical_Bessel_function_2k(unsigned int,
std::complex<double>)':
GUSTAVsolution.cpp:(.text+0x3dc): undefined reference to `zbesy_wrap'
GUSTAVsolution.cpp:(.text+0x53d): undefined reference to `zbesj_wrap'
/tmp/mex_7456790284416_24518/GUSTAVsolution.o: In function `MIEsolution::Spherical_Bessel_function_1k(unsigned int,
std::complex<double>)':
GUSTAVsolution.cpp:(.text+0x7a0): undefined reference to `zbesj_wrap'
GUSTAVsolution.cpp:(.text+0x907): undefined reference to `zbesy_wrap'
/tmp/mex_7456790284416_24518/GUSTAVsolution.o: In function
`MIEsolution::Differentation_Spherical_Hankel_function(unsigned int, std::complex<double>, int)':
GUSTAVsolution.cpp:(.text+0xb32): undefined reference to `zbesh_wrap'
GUSTAVsolution.cpp:(.text+0xc4f): undefined reference to `zbesh_wrap'
GUSTAVsolution.cpp:(.text+0xd30): undefined reference to `zbesh_wrap'
GUSTAVsolution.cpp:(.text+0xe4d): undefined reference to `zbesh_wrap'
/tmp/mex_7456790284416_24518/GUSTAVsolution.o: In function
`MIEsolution::Differentation_Spherical_Bessel_function(unsigned int, std::complex<double>, int)':
GUSTAVsolution.cpp:(.text+0xfb8): undefined reference to `zbesj_wrap'
GUSTAVsolution.cpp:(.text+0x112b): undefined reference to `zbesy_wrap'
GUSTAVsolution.cpp:(.text+0x1303): undefined reference to `zbesj_wrap'
GUSTAVsolution.cpp:(.text+0x1476): undefined reference to `zbesy_wrap'
GUSTAVsolution.cpp:(.text+0x161a): undefined reference to `zbesy_wrap'
GUSTAVsolution.cpp:(.text+0x1787): undefined reference to `zbesj_wrap'
GUSTAVsolution.cpp:(.text+0x1935): undefined reference to `zbesy_wrap'
GUSTAVsolution.cpp:(.text+0x1aa2): undefined reference to `zbesj_wrap'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

One of my functions that these errors happen is:

```
    complex<double> MIEsolution::Spherical_Bessel_function_2k(unsigned n,complex<double> z){

    complex<double> Sb2k;

        Sb2k = sph_besselY(n, z);

    return Sb2k;

}
```

The point is that this library connects some Fortran code with C++. For example, the `sph_besselY` function will call the appropriate Fortran code `zbesy_wrap`.

Am I suppose to compile the Fortran functions somehow? I installed the library the same way as the webpage does. Also, I am importing the library to my code, like that:

```
#include <complex_bessel.h>
```

Comment: Show your linker command... You link the compiled C with the compiled Fortran.
There are symbol issues like trailing underscores, etc to work out with either compiler switches or with BIND(C...) In fortran there is USE ISO_C_BINDING. You probably want a simple example. There are built in BESSEL functions in fortran that are ELEMENTAL...

Answer (score 0):

To fix this add the linker flag `-lcomplex_bessel`, as suggested here:

[Compile simpleTest.cpp errors](https://github.com/valandil/complex_bessel/issues/7)

in Code::Blocks IDE I set this flag in `Project->Build Options...->Linker Settings->Other linker options:` text-box.
As for the `mex`, I don't know if this one `mex GUSTAVsolution.cpp -lcomplex_bessel` is going to work, but for sure you should add this linker flag somehow!

Comment: How do you know the OP uses Code::Blocks?

Comment: @VladimirF I don't know that, I guess he uses the Matlab mex compiler! But I use g++ and C::B, so those give the same error unless the `-lcomplex_bessel` flag is set to the linker. So as a compiler the Matlab mex compiler should also have the option to give linker flags somehow!